# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str Python/MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm writing a stock tracker app for myself with a python backend, i needed to add an update statement in and when i do the code no longer functions - I get the error, "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str."

The incert statements work fine and if i remove this it all works again. Any ideas where i am going wrong with this?

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("UPDATE stock_mains.user_stock SET user_stock1_price = '" + stock_live_price + "' WHERE user_id = 'da_mike' AND user_stock1 is NOT NULL")
mydb.commit()
```

```
     if market_status == "REGULAR":
         mycursor = mydb.cursor()
         sql = "INSERT INTO stock_live (Stock_symbol, Stock_live_price, stock_datetime, stock_volume, stock_marketcap, stock_dayrange, stock_open, stock_previousclose) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
         val = (arg, stock_live_price, timestamp, volume, marketcap, dayrange, openprice, previousclose)
         mycursor.execute(sql, val)
         mydb.commit()
         stock_live_int = float(stock_live_price)
         print(round(stock_live_int, 2))
     elif market_status == "PRE":
         stock_premarket_price = si.get_premarket_price(arg)                   
         mycursor = mydb.cursor()
         sql = "INSERT INTO stock_live (Stock_symbol, stock_premarket_price, stock_datetime, stock_volume, stock_marketcap, stock_dayrange, stock_open, stock_previousclose) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
         val = (arg, stock_premarket_price, timestamp, volume, marketcap, dayrange, openprice, previousclose)
         mycursor.execute(sql, val)
         mydb.commit()
         print(stock_premarket_price)
         print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")  
         
     elif market_status == "POST":
         stock_postmarket_price = si.get_postmarket_price(arg)                   
         mycursor = mydb.cursor()
         sql = "INSERT INTO stock_live (Stock_symbol, stock_aftermarket_price, stock_datetime, stock_volume, stock_marketcap, stock_dayrange, stock_open, stock_previousclose) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
         val = (arg, stock_postmarket_price, timestamp, volume, marketcap, dayrange, openprice, previousclose)
         mycursor.execute(sql, val)
         mydb.commit()
         print(stock_postmarket_price) 
         print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")                 
     elif market_status == "CLOSED":
         mycursor = mydb.cursor()
         mycursor.execute("UPDATE stock_mains.user_stock SET user_stock1_price = '" + stock_live_price + "' WHERE user_id = 'da_mike' AND user_stock1 is NOT NULL")
         mydb.commit()
         print("Market is Closed")                       
         stock_live_int = float(stock_live_price)
         print(round(stock_live_int, 2))
         


   
     time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Python doesn't let you add strings and numbers together.  Use `str(stock_live_price)`instead.

Comment: perfect, that worked - thanks a lot John

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections. You can change your query to convert the float value to str:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
query = "UPDATE stock_mains.user_stock SET user_stock1_price = %s WHERE user_id = 'da_mike' AND user_stock1 is NOT NULL" 
mycursor.execute(query, (str(stock_live_price),))
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks I am using prepared statments but was trying different things just in case the SQL was the issue but I don't think it is.